# Expected Value for defined Random Variables $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, random-variables, expected-value

[image]

I don't understand what the random variables here mean exactly. $B$ is a $5$ element subset of the set $A$.

$X$ over here is defined by $B$ intersection ${a,b,c,d}$. Does this mean that ${a,b,c,d}$ is part of the $5$ element subset of $B$? I'm assuming I have to use the indicator variables to solve this.

If I define $X = 1$ as $B$ intersection ${a,b,c,d}$,

so $E(X) =  P(X=1) = $${5}\choose{2}$ * ${4}\choose{2}$ / ${8}\choose{2}$ ?

I know for independence, $P(X=x)*P(Y=y) = P(X=x $ $ and $ $ Y=y)$

But again, I'm not sure what the defined random variables mean, how should I solve this problem, it's been a struggle for the last couple of hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is pointed out, $|A|$ denotes the cardinality (the number of elements) of $A$. Thus we may write
$$
X = \sum_{x=a,b,c,d} 1_{x \in B},$$ and $$Y = \sum_{x=e,f,g,h}1_{x\in B}$$ where $1_{z\in E}$ denotes the indicator function (taking values in $\{0,1\}$ whose value is $1$ if and only if the $z\in E$.) We can immediately observe that
$$
X+Y =|B| = 5.
$$ This readily implies that $X$ and $Y$ are dependent. And since expectation operation is linear, we have
$$
E[X] = \sum_{x=a,b,c,d} E[1_{x \in B}] = \sum_{x=a,b,c,d} P(x \in B).
$$ For arbitrary $x$, it holds that
$$
P(x\in B) = \frac{\binom{7}{4}}{\binom{5}{8}} = \frac{5}{8}.
$$Hence, this gives
$$
E[X] = 4\cdot\frac{5}{8} = \frac{5}{2},
$$ and $$
E[Y] =\frac{5}{2}$$ also follows.

Comment: I'm a little lost on the 1 z is an element in E part. What does that mean the indicator function taking values 0,1? Also, how is X+Y=|B|? Shouldn't it be equal to A because A has {a.b.c.d.e.f.g}? And where is 5Choose8 coming from?

Comment: I used $z$ and $E$ as generic variables. The Indicator function $1_{z\in E}$, also called characteristic function, is a $0$-$1$ function which has value $1$ if $z\in E$ and $0$ if $z\not\in E$. We can see that $X+Y$ is the number of $x\in A$ such that $x\in B$. Hence $X+Y=|B|=5$. We choose $5$-set randomly. So there's $\binom{8}{5}$ possibilities of $B$. Among them, exactly $\binom{7}{4}$ sets contain $x$.

Answer (score 1):

For $A$ any set, the notation $|A|$ denotes the cardinality of $A$, i.e. the number of elements the set $A$ contains.